# Invisible field on condition in odoo

Tags: odoo

I have one field which i want to hide when specific journal selected.

```xml
<field name="any_field" attrs="{'invisible':[('journal_id','=',10])]}"/>
```

And For that above code is working fine.

I sure it is not a way to check condition.So, i tried this way.

```xml
<field name="any_field" attrs="{'invisible':[('journal_id','=',ref('my_module.account_journal_10'))]}"/>
```

It's working then i tried by using the static field on the journal eg. code.

```xml
<field name="any_field" attrs="{'invisible':[('journal_id.code','=','CARD')]}"/>
```

But still not working and getting error from view.

I am thinking if i can return the attrs from .py like i do for domain.

eg.

```py
return {'domain':
            {
              'any_field':[('journal_id','=',self.env.ref('my_module.account_journal_10').id)]
            }
        }
```

Can anybody help me in this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know these `attrs` domains/filters are client-side so you can't use something like `journal_id.code` or `partner_id.customer`, because the client doesn't know about such data.

A possible workaround is to define a related field on the model you're trying to do this. Let's assume the model is `my.model` and already has this `Many2one` field `journal_id`:

```py
journal_code = fields.Char(string="Journal Code", related="journal_id.code")
```

Now you need to extend the view of `my.model`:

```xml
<field name="journal_code" invisible="1" />
<field name="any_field" attrs="{'invisible':[('journal_code','=','CARD')]}"/>
```